# What or is there a difference in Adonai and Adonoy?

Tags: blessing, hebrew, grammar-dikduk

I have just started learning Hebrew and I found a transliteration for the after meal blessing which includes Adonai and Adonoy; what is the difference between the two?

“Baruch ha-gever asher yivtach ba'**Adonai** ve-haya **Adonoy** mivtacho.”

I apologize if this was asked with specific words in Hebrew but it is beyond my understanding at the moment.

Comment: Where did you find this transliteration (and where is this part of an after meal blessing)? This is from Jeremiah 17:7 which is used in the Uva L'tziyon.

Comment: These two words are identical, and your transliteration is inconsistent. @rosends See: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Birkat_Hamazon%2C_Birkat_Hamazon%2C_Hatov_Vehametiv.13

Comment: @Kazibácsi thanks -- I was thinking he meant the blessing, itself and was confused.

Answer (score 1):

If one looks at the Hebrew of the letters of Hashem's name [in בּרכּת המזון in the section of יראו את] are exactly the same. The difference in translation is just some people arguing how it is spelled but it makes no difference.

Comment: I removed the bit at the end which is completely irrelevant to the question at hand. Please try to make sure your answers stay on topic.